# Fill runtime data at compile time with templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c-preprocessor, c++14

I have a specific situation in which I would like to prepare some runtime structures at compile time without the need to duplicate code.

I have two structs that I use to register at compile time some types for a compiler I wrote:

```
using TypeID = u8;

template<typename T, typename TYPE_ID, TYPE_ID I>
struct TypeHelper
{
  static constexpr TYPE_ID value = std::integral_constant<TYPE_ID, I>::value;
};

template<typename T> struct Type : TypeHelper<T, u8, __COUNTER__> { static_assert(!std::is_same<T,T>::value, "Must specialize for type!"); };
```

These are used in a config header with a macro that specialize `Type<T>` for multiple types I require:

```
using type_size = unsigned char;

#define GET_NTH_MACRO(_1,_2,_3, NAME,...) NAME
#define REGISTER_TYPE(...) GET_NTH_MACRO(__VA_ARGS__, REGISTER_TYPE3, REGISTER_TYPE2, REGISTER_TYPE1)(__VA_ARGS__)

#define REGISTER_TYPE1(_TYPE_) REGISTER_TYPE2(_TYPE_, _TYPE_)

#define REGISTER_TYPE2(_TYPE_,_NAME_) \
constexpr TypeID TYPE_##_NAME_ = __COUNTER__; \
template<> struct Type<_TYPE_> : TypeHelper<_TYPE_, type_size, TYPE_##_NAME_> { \
  static constexpr const char* name = #_NAME_; \
};

REGISTER_TYPE(void)
REGISTER_TYPE(s64)
REGISTER_TYPE(s32)
```

so that these expand to

```
constexpr TypeID TYPE_void = 2; 
template<> struct Type<void> : TypeHelper<void, type_size, TYPE_void> { static constexpr const char* name = "void"; };

constexpr TypeID TYPE_s64 = 3; 
template<> struct Type<s64> : TypeHelper<s64, type_size, TYPE_s64> { static constexpr const char* name = "s64"; };

constexpr TypeID TYPE_s32 = 4;
template<> struct Type<s32> : TypeHelper<s32, type_size, TYPE_s32> { static constexpr const char* name = "s32"; };
```

This is working fine but the compiler also requires some runtime information about these types, so in addition to this I must define some auxiliary functions like

```
static TypeID typeForIdent(const std::string& name);
static const char* nameForType(TypeID type);
static void mapTypeName(TypeID type, const std::string& name);

inline bool isSigned(TypeID type)
{
  return type == Type<s8>::value || type == Type<s16>::value ||
  type == Type<s32>::value || type == Type<s64>::value;
}
```

and similar functions.

These functions must work without template arguments, so that `TypeID` must be a normal argument. But I'm required to initialize such data in a separate part of code, eg:

```
mapTypeName(Type<s32>::value, "s32");
```

which uses a static `std::unordered_map<TypeID, std::string>`. Of course this also implies that I must maintain twice the code when most of the information is already available at compile time through the types defines.

I was wondering if there's some obscure trick which I'm missing which could coalesce these so that `REGISTER_TYPE` macro also registers the runtime information. I haven't come with anything yet but maybe there's a clever way to manage this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not particularly concerned with the performance of registering your run-time data into the map, you could simply use an `inline` function that returns a reference to a `static` map instance, and generate *"dummy"* `registrar` instances in your `REGISTER_TYPE` macro that fill the map in their constructor.

---

```
inline auto& registration_map()
{
    static std::unordered_map<int, std::string> m;
    return m;
}

struct registrar 
{ 
    registrar(int id, std::string s) 
    {
        registration_map()[id] = std::move(s);   
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct TypeHelper { };

#define CAT3_IMPL(a, b, c) a ## b ## c
#define CAT3(a, b, c) CAT3_IMPL(a, b, c)

#define REGISTER_TYPE(id, type) \
    template<> struct TypeHelper<type> { }; \
    [[maybe_unused]] registrar CAT3(unused_registrar_, __LINE__, type) {id, #type};

REGISTER_TYPE(0, int)
REGISTER_TYPE(1, float)
REGISTER_TYPE(2, double)

int main()
{
    assert(registration_map()[0] == "int");
    assert(registration_map()[1] == "float");
    assert(registration_map()[2] == "double");
}
```

[**Full example on wandbox**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/bjGbVOY7O1jnnlf2).

---

Notes:

- You may get repeated registrations if the same `REGISTER_TYPE` is included in multiple translation units.
- `CAT3(unused_registrar_, __LINE__, type)` is used to generate an unique name that will not collide with other `REGISTER_TYPE` expansions.

Comment: The line number isn't substituted for `__LINE__` in `unused_registrar_ ## __LINE__ ## type`. You must use a helper macro.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen you use c++ extension `__COUNTER__` and as such maybe you will find interesting string literal gcc and clang extension which would allow you to bind string literal expressing registered type directly to your `Type` (without additional identification number):

```
#include <iostream>

template <class Char, Char... Cs>
struct string_literal { 
    static Char str[sizeof...(Cs) + 1]; 
};

template <class Char, Char... Cs>
Char string_literal<Char, Cs...>::str[sizeof...(Cs) + 1] = { Cs..., '\0' };

template <class Char, Char... Cs>
constexpr string_literal<Char, Cs...> operator ""_sl() {
    return {};
}

template <class T, class SL>
struct TypeHelper { };

template <class T>
struct Type;

template <class A, class B>
auto getType(TypeHelper<A, B>) {
    return B{};
}

#define REGISTER(TYPE) template <> \
     struct Type<TYPE>: TypeHelper<TYPE, decltype(#TYPE##_sl)> { };

struct X{};

REGISTER(void)
REGISTER(int)
REGISTER(X)

int main(){
    std::cout << decltype(getType(Type<void>{}))::str << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

> void

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ALjVNwi4O4D5iFqD)